# Show HTML div element which has class "hide" in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, hide, show

I have this simple `<div>`:

```
<div id='myId' class='hide'>...</div>
```

I want to show it using the class `show`.

```
$("#myId").show();
```

It doesn't work, the `<div>` keeps the `hide` class.

Comment: The class `show` or the method `show()` as in your posted code? Looks like you just need to remove the `hide` class. And btw, your title is referring to `hide()` method, your posted code shows the use of a class `hide`. Really not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.juery.com/toggleclass) as follows:

```
$("#myId").toggleClass("hide show");
```

or

```
$("#myId").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
```

Comment: +1 but rereading unclear OP's question, i guess he just wants/needs to remove `hide` class

Comment: @A.Wolff not sure what is there in his CSS, but he says *"I want to show it using the class show"*..

Answer (score 2):

[`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) won't change the class of the element(s) it is called on, it will simply change the necessary CSS styles to hide it from the user.

To remove the class, use [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```
$('#myId').show().removeClass('hide');
```

If you are using the `.hide` and `.show` CSS classes to toggle visibility of your elements, just use `.show()` and `.hide()` methods. Otherwise, simply removing your class will do:

```
$('#myId').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: +1 but I guess `$('#myId').removeClass('hide')` would be enough

Answer (score 0):

Use callback

```
$("#myId").show('slow',function(){
                                 $(this).removeClass('hide');
               });
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

`<div id='myId' class='hide'>...</div>`

**JS/JQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("#myId").removeClass("hide");
});

//or remove all of class hide

$(function() {
    $(".hide").each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hide");
    });
});

//or use the JQuery METHOD(S) to do the same which is class unrelated

$(function() {
    $("#myId").show();
    //or
    $("#myId").hide();
    //or
    $("#myId").fadeToggle(); //opacity animation based
    $("#myId").slideToggle(); //position animation based
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it like this and .show() will work:

`<div id="myId" style="display:none">...</div>`